# NSPredicate timestamp without date

Tags: swift, core-data, nsdate, nspredicate

I'm using `NSPredicate` to fetch items from Core Data. The items have to have a creation time between 4 pm and 6 pm. How can I use `NSPredicate` to do this? Right now I'm using:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "time >= \(startTime) AND time <= \(endTime)")
```

But this also takes the date into account and I only want it to check the time. Is this possible using `NSPredicate` or should I just fetch all the items, remove the date manually and then filter out the items by checking the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really add an 'hour time stamp' to the entity, which could be automatically set when your existing date time values are updated and which you can use for fetch predicates. Predicates and examine date time stamps but only from a <=> perspective (as your current code uses).

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to change my entity then. Do you also know how much of a performance decrease it would give if I limit the fetch results to about 500 and then filter it manually?

Comment: Processing 500 items will be quick, but based on your stated requirement I don't see how you're going to choose the 500 items to return (the newest?)

Comment: Ah ok, thats good to know. The example above is only a little snippet of my code. The original has more predicates. I guess the cleanest way is still adding an hour time stamp like you have suggested.